# What is the most efficient way of adding values from different scales to create a metric? Normalization v/s Scaling v/s?

Tags: normalization, feature-scaling

I'm working on creating a metric to evaluate medical protocols with different factors. The proportion of weightage of each factor is determined by a survey which we have calculated as below :

Factor a : 65%
Factor b : 10%
Factor c : 15%
Factor d :   5%
Factor e :   5%

Now the issue is that all these factors are obviously with different units and hence different scales in values.

Let's say I have the following data:

| protocol | factorA | factorB | factorC | factorD | factorE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 256 | 20 | 0.1 | 0.9 | 2089 |
| 234 | 610 | 24 | 0.31 | 0.4 | 2871 |
| 345 | 789 | 57 | 0.1 | 0.4 | 5782 |

To use the proportional metric formula, I need to bring all these figures into a common scale i.e. either normalized form or a scaled form.
As of now I'm using a min max scaling to convert each factor to a scale of 1-5 and then adding them weighted proportionally.

My question is given the fact that the protocol data is dynamic, and it is going to keep on growing, what is the most appropriate method, statistically to compare such figures.

Comment: What do these min and max values represent? Bounds of possible range? of somehow narrower, trimmed range? Will the bounds dynically change? Also, do you think you need to consider shapes of distributions of the "factors" (one factor could be right skew, another left skew)

Comment: The min-max range of 1-5 represents a relative score i need to give after taking in consideration the above mentioned factors. This scale needs to be consistent. The bounds of the values for various factors will change dynamically. As of now I'm not considering shape of distributions.